# Understanding Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

**Question 1:**

```
   var _curry1 = function _curry1(fn) {
        return function f1(a) {
            if (arguments.length === 0) {
                return f1;
            } else if (a != null && a['@@functional/placeholder'] === true) {
                return f1;
            } else {
                return fn.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
    };
```

What is the purpose of checking `a['@@functional/placeholder'] === true` ?

**Question 2:**

http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/docs/#reduce

How do I read the notation?

`(a,b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`

This is my first time seeing such notation, where does it come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**

There is no "notation". [__.js](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/8db95ee88b25a5b28f1fa02d72ab6f22ef4f8166/src/__.js) should clear it up:

```
module.exports = {'@@functional/placeholder': true};
```

so `@@functional/placeholder` is no different than `foo` in

```
a = { foo: true }
a.foo
a["foo"]
```

(Obviously, you can't write `a.@@functional/placeholder` because of all the odd symbols there.)

The intent is also seen in that file:

```
/**
 * A special placeholder value used to specify "gaps" within curried functions,
 * allowing partial application of any combination of arguments,
 * regardless of their positions.
 *
 * If `g` is a curried ternary function and `_` is `R.__`, the following are equivalent:
 *
 *   - `g(1, 2, 3)`
 *   - `g(_, 2, 3)(1)`
 *   - `g(_, _, 3)(1)(2)`
 *   - `g(_, _, 3)(1, 2)`
 *   - `g(_, 2, _)(1, 3)`
 *   - `g(_, 2)(1)(3)`
 *   - `g(_, 2)(1, 3)`
 *   - `g(_, 2)(_, 3)(1)`
 ...
```

So the intent is to be able to "skip" some places when currying. The test decides whether an argument is a real argument or the `__.js` placeholder, and behaves accordingly. Why it is `@@functional/placeholder` - presumably precisely because it is hoped that it is too weird, and will thus not collide with anyone's legitimate data.

**Question 2:**

The notation is standard in type theory, and popularised by Haskell. `a` and `b` are any types. `(...)` is a tuple of types, `[a]` is an list whose elements are `a`. `a -> b` is a function that takes an argument of type `a` and yields a return of type `b`, and is right-associative. The example in question reads:

It is a function that takes an argument a function that takes two arguments (of types `a` and `b` respectively) and returns a value of type `a`; and yields a function that takes an argument of type `a` and returns a function that takes an argument that is a list of elements of type `b`, returning a value of type `a`.

This reads very confusingly, but an uncurried description will be a bit easier: it is a function that takes three arguments: the first one being a function (as described above), the second one being a value of `a`, the third one being a list of `b` elements, and returns a value of `a`.

Specifically, `R.reduce` is such a function: in

```
R.reduce(add, 10, numbers);
```

`add` is a function that takes two integers (both `a` and `b` being the same, integer), and returns an integer (`(a, b) -> a`); `10` is of type integer (`a`); numbers is a list of integers (`[b]`); and the return value is an integer (`a`).

Note that it mixes curried and uncurried syntax; if it was fully curried, `add` would be `a -> b -> a`, not `(a, b) -> a`.

Comment: "Why it is `@@functional/placeholder` - presumably precisely because it is hoped that it is too weird, and will thus not collide with anyone's legitimate data."  That and there's a hope that other libraries might decide to use this same token and could inter-operate regarding the placeholder.  It seemed better than using something Ramda-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Question 2:

That is a Hindley-Milner type signature.  For the example given, 'a' and 'b' are arbitrary types and '->' is a function.

So lets break it down.

First, we take a type 'a' and a function 'b -> a'

(a, b -> a)

This returns a function, which returns a function,.. (cause you know, currying).  The point is we can add '()' to make it a bit more readable.

(a, b -> a) -> (a -> ([b] -> a))

So if you pass this function 'a' and a function 'a' -> 'b', you get back

a -> ([b] -> a)

And if you pass this a type 'a'

[b] -> a

Where [b] is an array of type 'b's.  Passing this function [b] gives you
a type a

a

If you want to read more about functional programming in JavaScript, I can recommend [The Mostly Adequate Guide](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/)

Comment: Not your fault, and I had to change my answer, but due to (I assume) sloppiness, `a,b -> a` was meant as `(a, b) -> a`, not as `(a, (b -> a))` as one would expect. The example given on the page for this signature was `var add = (a, b) => a + b;`.